# Is there any performance problem when all other operation are executed on a thread that blocking operation is executed when I used subscribeOn

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` for executing some blocking code in my spring webflux application , but after the execution of block section has finished other operation that applied on that stream are executed on the thread that the block segment is executed , is that make any performance issue or something bad in my application? if yes what can I do , or how can I switch back to Main thread after execution of blocking section.

My code is something like below :

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> blockingOperation())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .map(response -> response.getId())
```

as you can see the blockingOperation ia executed on a seperate thread and when the response is returned I get the id from that response by map operation that is executed on the thread that the blocking method has already been executed . I know about the behavior of subscribeOn method , but I want to know that is there any problem about the above code? suppose that in my real scenario I have more than just one map operation.

Comment: Unless you do some very CPU intensive operation, it is unlikely to cause any issues. If you must, you can switch to another scheduler using publishOn. Schedulers.parallel could be a good choice, if no blocking IO is involved.

Comment: I have some db operation and service call from another services(I can't use webclient in my project now) ,  what  is difference between using subscribeOn and publishOn , i know that subscribeOn is switch the thread for all stream and publishOn is just for down stream but what can this effect performance? and why you say parallel is better choice than bundedElastic because I think if I use parallel the requests that  can be handled decreases.